# Passing dynamic input fields from view to controller in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm building a form with Bootstrap in a Laravel 5.2 view, where I will have an option to add additional input fields like you can [see here in this link.](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/)

So, I will essentially need to be passing a PHP array of data (I think) to my controller. I'm just trying to comprehend how exactly I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
 <div id="dynamicInput">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"></span>
 </div>
```

javascripts:

```
function addInput(divName)
{ 
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='items[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);    
}
```

you can have array of items this way.

and in your controller to save these.

```
 foreach($items as $item)
    {
     if(!empty($item))
      {     
        $add=new Item();   //Item is the model
        $add->name=$item;  //saving item to name column
        $add->save();       
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, this will be perfect. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ajax ( jQuery )

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your/array/route',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {

        if(data.result != null) {
            $.each(data.result, function(i, v) {
                $("#form").append('<input type="text" value="'+v.your_value+'">');
            );
        }
    }
});
```